# How can I organize my project in a git repository?

Tags: git

I have four kinds of files (source code, databases, docs and executable files)
should I put all of them in the Git repo or should i put only the source code in the repo?

**Is there any standard structure to organize my project files?**

Thank you

Comment: What kind of project it is? C/Python/Ruby, website development, standalone app, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should definitely track your source code in your git repository.
- Don't track in your repository anything that's generated from your source code, such as object files, executables and documentation generated with javadoc or doxygen (for example).  You can safely use `.gitignore` to stop git from suggesting you add any such  generated files to your repository.
- If by "databases" you mean a the filesystem backing of a relational database (such as an sqlite file) you shouldn't be tracking that in your repository.  It'll change very frequently, and quickly inflate your repository.

Although people use git for all kinds of strange purposes, in many respects it's tailored for handling source code.

The structure of your project files isn't determined by git - it should be suggested by the tools, language, operating system, etc. etc. that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you put everything in the repository that is needed to build and test the application.  So all source code, database creation scripts, test scripts, etc. go into the repository.

Typically you don't put any of the "products" (executables, generated documentation, etc.) into the repository, although some people do do this when they do a release.